surreal short film with 3 "nations" with primary color paint; shown at World Expo in 1986-87
There was a beautiful silent film I saw at the World Expo in Vancouver in 1987. In it, there are 3 "nations", each of which has its own color -- red, blue, and yellow. They are in a state of tense cold war. There are also 2 "star crossed lovers" from different "countries" who can see each other with telescopes. One "lover" travels to the other's "country", which leads to his (?) imprisonment by that country, which launches "war" (throwing paint at each other), and there's a VERY touching ending.
Anyone know the title of the film or where I can find it? It would mean a lot to me! (I'm actually getting teary-eyed remembering the movie!)

According to Google, the World Expo in Vancouver was in 1986 (my birth year!).
Appears the title of the film is Rainbow War, 19 minutes long and directed by Bob Rogers. 
Wikipedia:

Once upon a time, in a timeless place, there were three kingdoms: one
  blue, one red, and one gold. In the blue kingdom, everything was blue,
  because blue was beautiful. And besides, everyone who was anyone loved
  blue. In the red land, everything was red, because they trusted red,
  but they were afraid of everything else. The golden kingdom was
  dominated by yellow. Other colours were to be eliminated on sight.
  Blue and red were censored, covered up, thus yellow reigned supreme.
But it really didn't matter if the kingdoms didn't like each other,
  for, you see, travel between the kingdoms was impossible. So they
  never came into contact. In isolation, each kingdom taught its young
  what to like and dislike. Other ideas were discouraged, but it
  couldn't last forever. In time, there came a new idea... a moving new
  idea... and the world would never be the same!

IMDb:

Three kingdoms, floating separately in space, can each see the other
  nearby kingdoms but have no means to communicate or visit. Each has
  developed a fanatical obsession for a specific color for clothing,
  architecture, and even plant life: one blue, one red, one golden. A
  forbidden inter-kingdom romance and a war of conquest ensues when a
  means of travel between the kingdoms is abruptly found.


That's the one! Thanks!  BTW, although the World Expo in Vancouver started in 1986, it continued through 1987. Our souvenirs all say "1986" but we went to the expo the following summer. :)

Wikipedia say it ended in 1986, and I trust that more than my memory. 1986 was a long time ago!!
